# How do I overlay a pattern on a PNG using Pillow in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

I want to overlay a certain pattern on a shirt in Pillow Python, this is my code -

```
design =Image.open("source/stripe.png").convert("RGBA")
shirtsketchtrans = Image.open("source/shirtsketchtrans.png").convert("RGBA")

design.paste(shirtsketchtrans, (0,0), shirtsketchtrans)
design.show()
```

The outcome coming is this -
[image: I don't mind the size, that can be fixed]

I don't really mind the size, that can be fixed.
But what I want to do is have the striped pattern overlay **only** on my shirt PNG and not in the whole background, basically get the pattern only **on** my shirt and nowhere else.

Is there any solution to this?
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Edit: Input/Source Images -

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll need to provide the input images please.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sorry, I added them in now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PIL on its own isn't smart enough to know what's "inside" or "outside" the shirt. You need to make a [Transparency Mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)#Image_masks) and then use [`PIL.Image.composite`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=mask#PIL.Image.composite) to combine them.

Example:

```
design = Image.open("source/stripe.png").convert("RGBA")
shirt_sketch_trans = Image.open("source/shirtsketchtrans.png").convert("RGBA")
shirt_sketch_mask = Image.open("source/shirtsketchmask.png").convert("RGBA")

full_design = Image.composite(design, shirt_sketch_trans, shirt_sketch_mask)
full_design.show()
```

Comment: Hey, I understand how this would work in theory but I am getting the "Value Error: images do no match" now after executing this code (I created the mask and everything as well)

Comment: Update: I don't know the issue with composite, I just used the paste twice and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ADUCJ my bad, I missed that your images were different sizes. I was going to suggest using paste to get design to be the same size as shirt_sketch, but you figured that out on your own, nice!